# Need help triggering http request in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform

I've created a function in Flutter that sends jsonData to the Google Cloud Function I created with a sendgrid API. I'm having trouble getting it to trigger though. I'm only a month in with flutter so this is all fairly new to me. Here is a snippet.

```html
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wequilschool_app/authentication/providers/auth_provider.dart';

class EmailServiceProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  EmailServiceProvider({required this.auth});
  //This email service provider needs the AuthProvider otherwise it won't work
  AuthProvider auth;

  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  List<String> generateEmailListFromString() {
    List<String> allEmails = [];
    // Long string with emails "a, b, c" assuming a, b and c are emails
    String userEmailString = controller.text;

    // Extract each email and place in allEmails
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    List<String> result = userEmailString.trim().split(',');

    for (String email in result) {
      if (email.contains('@')) {
        allEmails.add(email.trim());
      }
    }
    //Return this list
    return allEmails;
  }

  Future<void> sendInvitationEmail() async {
    String url = 'https://us-east4-wequilschoolapp.cloudfunctions.net/invite_user';

    // List of all emails invited by the user
    List<String> emailList = generateEmailListFromString();
    //Payload data the email needs
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = {
      'data': {
        'email': emailList,
        'inviter': auth.getUsername,
      }
    };

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    //describes the type of data of the http request
    request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    //encode the json data and add it to the http request
    request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonData)));
    //calls the request and return a val(ue?), then closes it
    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    //response of the request
    String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    httpClient.close();
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print(reply);
    print(response.statusCode);
  }
}
```

Comment: what the current output?

Comment: Nothing happens currently. The snippet is a part of a larger program I'm working with. I know the flutter function works as intended, but the trigger function I inserted won't respond. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: @ChineduNwabuisi Can you check if you can reach this function someway like using Postman or maybe testing this function by writing code in different language to check if you can get the output you want?

Comment: So part of the issue was that I didn't have the html script needed to make the firebase_database package work. I got that, but the app still wasn't working. After talking with a colleague I found out that the project we've been working on already has the cloud_firestore dependecy so I didn't need the other one after all. I have so much to learn

Comment: @ChineduNwabuisi If you already found the solution then can you please post it as an answer for visibility?